# Windows HotKey to go (focus)to the Desktop without minimizing all/any window(s)

Tags: windows, desktop, hotkeys

I know the keys <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> **sends me to the Desktop** in Windows.
And <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (since Vista) does the same as long as there is a *Desktop* icon on the *Task Switcher*.

But these methods **always minimize every** (most of them) window on the screen, and that is not always desired.

Is there **any hotkey (or simple keypressings)** to focus (position, select... whatever you call it) the Windows **Desktop without minimizing** all/any the windows?

Answer (score -1):

Press **sequentially**:

1.- <kbd>WinKey</kbd>

2.- <kbd>Esc</kbd>

3.- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

You should be now **focused on the Windows Desktop** (try typing the name of any of your icons, and it will be selected).

Valid for **any Windows version**, since Windows XP (and older). Pending to confirm for Windows 8.1 (if someone can, please test and report).

Comment: doesn't work for me under Windows 8 (the original not 8.1).

Comment: @magicandre1981, maybe pressing <kbd>WinKey</kbd> twice? (the first one to switch to that stupid mosaic screen, and the second one to show the desktop)

Comment: ok, I use StartIsBack, so maybe this causes it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score -2):

For Windows 10, press alt+esc.
It should unfocus all windows and focus on desktop.

Comment: Alt+Esc switches between 2 different windows/applications. The desktop is not part of this switching.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This answer seems to be incorrect. Unless you can argue to that, you should delete it or you could be downvoted.

Comment: Alt+Esc doesn't switch between 2 applications. It moves the focused window to the background and makes next window in the list the focused one.